# Accediendo a funciones sin ()

Tags: javascript

Creo que por definición, cuando se llama a addEventListener("click", function); la función recibe un argumento que es el objeto evento.
Tengo declarada una función con un parámetro. Concretamente al pulsar un botón, se ejecuta esta función.
Si la función que deseo que se ejecute cuando el evento ocurre, necesita un argumento,
porqué en la llamada a ella no es preciso proporcionarlo??

```
function displayNumeros(event) {

  cifra += event.currentTarget.value;
  document.getElementById("display").value = cifra;
  
}
/* Se supone que al llamar a la función displayNumeros(event); ésta 
   debiera recibir un argumento, pero no sólo no lo recibe sino que
   además sólo funciona si no lo recibe*/

listaNumeros  = document.getElementsByClassName("numero");
for (let i = 0; i < listaNumeros.length; i++) {
  listaNumeros[i].addEventListener("click", displayNumeros);//No debiera ser displayNumeros(event);?
  
}
```

Comment: No es necesario por que por defecto se le pasará, además no te haz dado cuenta que al crear la función en el mismo listener tampoco le pasas argumentos?

Comment: Creo que es un poco evidente pero se trata de redundancia, js es capaz de entender que lo que pasas es un metodo porque el eventListener recibe un metodo, asi que por defecto bindea los argumentos que se supone que el metodo tiene.

Comment: Puede que se le pase por defecto ese argumento pero si yo no declarase ese parámetro en la función 'displayNumeros(event)' supongo que no podría usarlo en el cuerpo del método.....Error, acabo de probarlo y la función puede usar el event sin recibirlo como argumento...

Comment: Claro, está bindeado en this, por eso es redundancia pasar los argumentos, lo mas valido seria si quieres destructurar el parametro, algo como: `mehotd( { type } )` y de esta manera solo obtener el dato que necesitas en especifico del objeto.

Comment: @Christian si le paso argumentos no funciona

Comment: Es que están mal entendiendo algo, cuando pasas un metodo lo estás ejecutando si o si, y si que es posible pasar el evento como parámetro pero no es lo mismo crear una función en el callback a pasarle una función en el mismo, si el método es anónimo no va a heredar this, no es lo mismo `let k = {
  love: 'love',
  feel: () => {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

k.feel()` a `let k = {
  love: 'love',
  feel() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

k.feel()`

Comment: @DєηyηCrawford y si lo pones en una respuesta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No es que no se proporcione el parámetro, el método *"sabe que lo debe enviar"* y, solo para no dejar lugar a dudas, vamos con algunas aclaraciones:

- Cuando asignas una función como parámetro, no debes incluir paréntesis porque se ejecutará inmediatamente.
- Aunque no se menciona en el manual, [.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) agregará el evento como parámetro a la función proporcionada por nombre, *sin paréntesis*.
- Aunque no asignes el evento como parámetro, puedes acceder a él desde [contexto global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event), pero no es muy recomendable, porque puede que esta opción desaparezca en el futuro.

```js
function conEvento(e) {
    if(e) {
        // Botón que recibió clic
        console.log(e.currentTarget);
    } else {
        // Evento no definido
        console.log(e);
    }
}

// No es recomendable, pero puedes obtener el evento desde contexto global
// Sin pasarlo como argumento a la función
function sinEvento() {
    console.log(event.currentTarget);
}

// Se ejecutará inmediatamente
// No se asigna la función al evento
// La variable event no se ha definido, porque no ha habido aún acción del usuario
document.querySelector('#btn1').addEventListener('click', conEvento(event));

// Especifica solo el nombre de la función
// Javascript asigna el evento como parámetro
document.querySelector('#btn2').addEventListener('click', conEvento);
document.querySelector('#btn3').addEventListener('click', sinEvento);
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Botón 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Botón 2</button>
<button id="btn3">Botón 3</button>
```

Otra opción es usar funciones anónimas, pero tampoco es muy recomendable:

```
document.querySelector('#btn2').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('Soy una función anónima');
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Como han dicho, el tema es que la función no se tiene que ejecutar en el momento en el que se define la funcion del evento, sino cuando se produce el evento.

En un pasado, la idea de [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) era la de manejar eventos con objetos, no necesariamente con funciones, precisamente objetos que usaran la interfaz `EventListener`. Dichos objetos tenían que implementar un método `handleEvent()`.

La idea era que mientras le pasemos un objeto x el método `addEventListener` iba a hacer `[...lo que le pasemos...].handleEvent({...el_objeto_del_contexto...})`. De esta manera, había que hacer un objeto por cada evento. Y lo que se pasaba era el objeto mismo.

**Esta era la manera de ejecutar una función en el "futuro", nos poníamos de acuerdo en un nombre de un método, y el evento siempre ejecutaba ese nombre**. Nosotros podíamos hacer distíntas "versiones" usando el mismo nombre, usando el truco de los objetos.

Luego se pudieron pasar funciones, pero como hacemos para no se ejecute en el momento? sino en el "futuro", basicamente lo mismo, pero le pasamos el nombre de la función en lugar del objeto.

Ejemplo de ambas formas, si lo imlementariamos en javascript:

```js
objetoDelEvento = {handleEvent:(e) => console.log(e)}


funcionDelEvento = (e) => console.log(e)

xNombreFuncion = (f) => {

  let func = Object.keys({
    f
  })[0]

  eval(`${func}('el contexto pasado a la funcion')`);

}


xObjeto = (o) => o.handleEvent("Este es el contexto pasado al objeto")


xNombreFuncion(funcionDelEvento); // <-- Nueva Forma

xObjeto(objetoDelEvento); // <-- Vieja Forma
```

Dicho sea de paso, aún hoy funciona la vieja forma, pasandole un objeto con el método `handleEvent`:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

Manejador = class {
  constructor() {}
  handleEvent = (e) => console.log(e);
}

const manejador = new Manejador(); // No es un nombre es un objeto

btn.addEventListener("click", manejador);// <-- Hace manejador.handleEvent(contexto)
```

```html
<button id="btn">
  boton
</button>
```

Un detalle de color, si pasamos un objeto como parámetro, no se valida que exista `.handleEvent`, valida solo que sea un objeto:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

btn.addEventListener("click", {});// <-- No lanza error, aunque no hace nada
btn.addEventListener("click", []);// <-- No lanza error, aunque no hace nada
```

```html
<button id="btn">
  boton
</button>
<button id="btn2">
  boton2
</button>
```

Comment: +1 Interesante la explicación de cómo funcionaba antes `addEventListener`, lo desconocía.

Answer (score 4):

Lo que pasa cuando invocas [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) es que estás **registrando** que cuando exista el tipo de evento que especificaste en el primer parámetro, se ejecute la función que especificaste en el segundo parámetro.

De forma tal que no eres tú el que hace la llamada a la función, sino es el motor de JS (o el navegador) quien la hace, en cuanto exista el evento.

También es el motor de JS el que pasa el argumento `event` a la función previamente especificada.

Te pongo un ejemplo, quizá un poco lejano a cómo funciona en realidad, pero que tal vez te pueda ayudar a entender mejor lo que acabo de explicar.

```js
/*** vamos a suponer que este codigo es el del navegador ***/

// asocia el nombre de un evento con los callbacks que se
// deben ejecutar cuando ocurre el evento
const eventsCallbacks = {
  click: [],
  hola: []
};

/**
 * Funcion que simula addEventListener
 * Registra una funcion a ejecutar cuando un "evento" ocurre
 * @param evt nombre del evento
 * @param fn funcion a ejecutar cuando el evento ocurre
 */
function addCallbackHook(evt, fn) { // simula addEventListener
 eventsCallbacks[evt].push(fn); // por simplicidad vamos a suponer que todos los parametros son validos y no hay errores
}

/*** fin de la suposicion ***/

/*** el siguiente codigo es el que tu escribes con js ***/

/**
 * Callback ejecutado cuando sucede un "evento" click
 * @param now la fecha en la cual sucedio el evento
 */
function onClick(now) {
 console.log("\"evento\" click sucedio a las", now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds());
}

/**
 * Callback ejecutado cuando sucede un "evento" hola
 * @param now la fecha en la cual sucedio el evento
 */
const onHola = (now) => {
  console.log("\"evento\" hola sucedio a las", now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds());
}

addCallbackHook("click", onClick);
addCallbackHook("hola", onHola);
addCallbackHook("hola", () => {
  console.log("Guardar las referencias a los callbacks en un arreglo permite la ejecucion de varios callbacks cuando el evento ocurre");
});

/*** nuevamente, vamos a suponer que este codigo es el del navegador ***/

const events = Object.keys(eventsCallbacks);

// vamos a simular eventos sucediendo aleatoriamente cada segundo
const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  const randomNumber = Math.random();
  if (randomNumber < 0.05) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    console.log("Generación de \"eventos\" detenida", randomNumber);
    return;
  }
  
  const randomEvent = events[Math.floor(randomNumber * events.length)];
  
  const now = new Date();

  // una vez que sucedio el evento, 
  // hay que ejecutar las funciones que fueron registradas
  // para ejecutarse cuando el evento ocurriera
  for (const callback of eventsCallbacks[randomEvent])
    callback(now); // <- aquí es donde realmente se invoca a la función
}, 1_000);
```

Digo que el ejemplo que di quizá sea *lejano a cómo funciona en realidad* puesto que seguramente las partes que dicen `vamos a suponer que este codigo es el del navegador` están hechas en C++ o algún otro lenguaje.

Ejecuta el código y analiza el output. Si inmediatamente se detiene, vuélvelo a ejecutar.

**Complemento**

Nótese que si escribieramos `addCallbackHook("click", onClick(new Date()))`, la llamada a `onClick(new Date())` retorna `undefined`, entonces realmente la llamada a `addCallbackHook("click", onClick(new Date()))` sería lo mismo que escribir `addCallbackHook("click", undefined)`.

Y eso lo que está "diciendo" es que registres que la función `undefined` se ejecute cuando el evento `click` suceda, lo cual no hace sentido, y de hecho con el ejemplo anterior surgiría un error.