# Event is deprecated

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo una aplicacion corta con javascript, que tiene q detectar el tecleo que el usuario digita en un input, el tema es que al hacerlo, me sale un warning en el vscode,

```
   let x = document.getElementById("jelou")

if(x){ //Tengo esto porque tenia un problema que me decia que x no era una funcion, pero esto me lo soluciona

x.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    var inputText = event.path[0].value; //aca el problema
    document.getElementById("numeros").innerHTML = inputText


})

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se como suplantar el programa, cualquier ayuda me sirve, muchas gracias

Comment: Solo agrega el evento como parámetro de la función: `x.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {` así ya no lo toma directo de `window.event` y deja de salir el mensaje.

Comment: Más información al respecto en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/462768/54039)

Comment: Muchas gracias Triby